# Text to visual animation in android

Tags: android

I have an android app in which I want to animate / visualize the text to speech . Like when the text is spoken by the app the app also blinks lights according to the voice data.

The data is available as text which I would convert to speech using text to speech of android.
The visual representation is like some LEDS blinking based on voice.

Can someone please me guideline how to extract voice data(which features to extract) and then how to map it to some visual animation ?

thanks, 
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

For the visualization you would use the [visualizer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html).  That will capture audio output and allow you to represent it visually.  I think for the text to speech you'd do better just to use existing engines.  Ivona and SVOX are two good ones if you don't like the stock engine.